# Issue in converting datatype in SQL Server 2005 Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am writing a stored procedure in which I am putting a condition if the value of the column `Field4` is less than or equal to 25, print the approval matrix for it, and if the value of the column `Field4` is greater than 25, print the corresponding approval matrix.

But this is not working, even if the value of `Field4` is greater than 25, it prints the approval matrix for the condition 'less than or equal to 25'.

The data type of the column `Field4` is `nvarchar(max)` and I am converting it to float since it contains amount whose values are for example- 1400.00, 25.79, 24.01 etc.

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[mccspGetApprovalMatrix3]
    @CaseId bigint
As 
   Declare @Query1 varchar(100)
   Declare @Query2 Float

   SET @Query1 = (Select Distinct [Group] 
                  from usertogroupmapping 
                  Where txtLoginId in (Select txtCreatedBy 
                                       from trnExecutionDetails 
                                       where intQueueFolderId = 2087 
                                         and intExecutionId = @CaseId))

   SET @Query2 = (Select convert (Float, Field4) 
                  from trnWebFormFieldsValues 
                  Where Field4 IS NOT NULL 
                    and flgActive = 1 
                    and intQueueFolderId = 2087)

   If @Query1 = 'E' OR @Query1 = 'F' 
   Begin 
       If @Query2 <= 25.00
       Begin
          Print 'L1- fpoint and dcoludro: L2- None: L3- None'
       End
       Else 
       Begin
          Print 'L1- pmorrone: L2- soberlies: L3- fpoint and dcoludro'
       End
   End
```

However when I am writing-

```
(Select convert (Float, Field4) 
 from trnWebFormFieldsValues 
 Where Field4 IS NOT NULL       
   and flgActive = 1 
   and intQueueFolderId = 2087 
   and Field4 <= 25)
```

it is showing correct results.

Can someone please look into it why it is not giving the correct result in the stored procedure?

Thanks in advance

Iftakhar Ahmad

Comment: Your `@Query1` variable will take an arbitrary (random) record from your select statement. Have you checked that the value of `@Query1` is what you expect? `@Query2` will also suffer the same fate if you get multiple records. Post some of your records to give us some more information. Also add some `PRINT` statements inside your stored procedure to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks a lot @marc_s, I was missing "Where intExecutionId = @CaseId" in the variable 'Query2'. 'Query2' was fetching multiple records.